# I can't FindControl in the more efficient way during RowDataBound event

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am working on filling two different labels from VB code behind. I currently have this working but I believe there is a much more efficient and better way of doing it. This is the only way I can find my labels without getting a Null reference exception. Again this works but what it does is go through each row multiple times (because of For Each Row....)

```
 Private Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound


    For Each Row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows

        Dim HFO1AD As String = DirectCast(Row.FindControl("HFO1AD"), HiddenField).Value
        Dim HFO2AD As String = DirectCast(Row.FindControl("HFO2AD"), HiddenField).Value
        Dim HFO3AD As String = DirectCast(Row.FindControl("HFO3AD"), HiddenField).Value
        Dim HFO4AD As String = DirectCast(Row.FindControl("HFO4AD"), HiddenField).Value
        Dim HFO5AD As String = DirectCast(Row.FindControl("HFO5AD"), HiddenField).Value
        Dim HFO6AD As String = DirectCast(Row.FindControl("HFO6AD"), HiddenField).Value

        Dim OfficialsAccepted As Label = DirectCast(Row.FindControl("OfficialsAcceptedlbl"), Label)
        Dim OfficialsNeeded As Label = DirectCast(Row.FindControl("OfficialsNeededlbl"), Label)
        Dim RowID As String = DirectCast(Row.FindControl("IDlbl"), HyperLink).Text

        Dim Cmd As SqlCommand
        Dim dr As SqlDataReader

        con.Open()
        Cmd = New SqlCommand("Select OfficialsNeeded From Schedule WHERE ID ='" + RowID + "'", con)

        dr = Cmd.ExecuteReader
        dr.Read()


        OfficialsNeeded.Text = dr(0).ToString
        con.Close()

        'Counting number of offiicials that have accepted
        Dim N As Integer = 0
        If HFO1AD = "Accept" Then
            N = N + 1
        End If
        If HFO2AD = "Accept" Then
            N = N + 1
        End If
        If HFO3AD = "Accept" Then
            N = N + 1
        End If
        If HFO4AD = "Accept" Then
            N = N + 1
        End If
        If HFO5AD = "Accept" Then
            N = N + 1
        End If
        If HFO6AD = "Accept" Then
            N = N + 1
        End If
        OfficialsAccepted.Text = N.ToString
    Next
End Sub
```

From what I have read the way you are to do this is like the following but I get a null reference exception (Can't find the control)

```
Dim HFO1AD As String = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("HFO1AD"), HiddenField).Value
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

I added the following if statement before my Dim statement and changed all my Dim statements back to look like this:

```
 If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then 

 Dim HFO2AD As String = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("HFO2AD"), HiddenField).Value
```